# The program returns some weird and incomplete string

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I am trying to write a function that delete whitespaces from a string but the output is not reasonable at all. I need help fam!

**Code:**

```c
char* deleteSpace(char *String, int n) {
    int i;
    char* withoutSpaces;
    withoutSpaces = calloc(n, sizeof (char));
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (String[i] == ' ')
            withoutSpaces[i] = String[++i];
        else
            withoutSpaces[i] = String[i];
    }
    return withoutSpaces;
}
```

Comment: Use two separate counters for `withoutSpaces` and `String`. When you `++i` the index for `withoutSpaces` skips a cell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have to indices a "read" index for the source string and a "write" index for the destination.

Also, for better debugability and readability, put the index increment, `++i` on a separate line.  Oh - it looks like you are incrementing `i` twice. Once implicitly by the loop and again with the `++i`.

Also unclear if n represents the length of the string with or without the null terminator.  So let's just let the function deal with figuring that out via strlen.

Don't forget to null terminate the output string.

Several other bugs as well.  Here's a version that's improved:

```
char* deleteSpace(const char *String) {

    int j = 0;
    const char* ptr = String;
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t spaces = 0;
    char* withoutSpaces = NULL;

    // count how many characters we expect to copy over
    while (*ptr) {
        n += (*ptr == ' ') ? 0 : 1;
        ptr++;
    }

    withoutSpaces = (char*)malloc(n+1); // +1 for null char

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (String[i] != ' ') {
            withoutSpaces[j] = String[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    withoutSpaces[j] = '\0';

    return withoutSpaces;
}
```

Also, if you just want to compact the string in place without allocating a new string.

```
void deleteSpace(char *String) {
    char* ptrWrite = String;
    while (*String) {
        if (*String != ' ') {
            *ptrWrite = *String;
            ptrWrite++;
        }
        String++;
    }
    *ptrWrite = '\0';
}
```

Comment: And to take it further, you could `realloc` the `withoutSpaces` string at end as `withoutSpaces = realloc(withoutSpaces, j+1)`. And make sure you `free` this memory upon return.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj - it appears the OP wants to return a new string. Hence, it's up to the caller to free the string.  I'll add a compact version that does what you suggest.

Comment: Correct, `free` is dependent on OP.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj - fixed with a variation of your suggestion.